# Autowire Objectmapper in RowMapper

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, rowmapper

I found [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183056/spring-autowiring-not-working/19183165?noredirect=1#comment104912510_19183165) say it possible to autowire inside rowmapper,

> If you want ScoreMapper instances to have ScoreCreator scoreCreator be injected with a Spring bean, the ScoreMapper instance itself must be a Spring bean, ie. created and managed by Spring

Or by adding [@Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061320/spring-managed-bean-injection-in-class-implementing-rowmapper/44062298)

> You can define PersonUtility class as spring bean adding @component over the class.

But currently RowMapper is instantiated with `new` in `jdbcTemplate.query`:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new Object[] {}, new MyRowMapper())
```

And I can't autowire Spring managed ObjectMapper inside

```
public class MyRowMapper implements RowMapper<Map<Integer, Type>> {

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("myObjectMapper")
   ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

How should I refactor current code to manage bean row mapper?

Comment: Have you annoted your MyRowMapper as @Component - if so, can you post the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RowMapper is a thread safe class. That means, it's single instance can be shared amongst multiple threads. So, that means, you can let it be a singleton class and let spring handle it's lifecycle (Using one of those annotation like @Component). And wherever you want to use it's instance, just autowire/inject existing instance rather than instantiating it every time (`new`)

```
@Component
public class MyRowMapper implements RowMapper<Map<Integer, Type>> {

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("myObjectMapper")
   ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

And then

```
class ASingletonClass(){
  @Autowired MyRowMapper myRowMapper;

  public MyRowMapper myAweSomeMethod(){
    return jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new Object[] {}, myRowMapper)
  }
}
```

Refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34955166/6785908). It's in similar lines